# Avoiding indexes in new pushed json nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, push

When I push a new json array into an existing array it indexes it with a 0 before cars and models.

Is there a way to avoid this?
Thanks

var myJsonArray = {
    baseID: '1',
    optionsArray: []
};

myJsonArray.optionsArray.push( myObj );

```
myObj = {
"cars": [
    { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
    { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
    { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
   ]
}
```

result:

`optionsArray:Array(1)
0:
  cars:(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__:Object
length:1
__proto__:Array(0)`

Comment: Yeah well if `optionsArray` is an array it will have indices?! If you dont want that dont use an array

Comment: Hard to make much sense out of what you are asking or expecting. Take a few minutes to help us help you by reading through [ask] then edit the question with a properly detailed pro blem description and a  [mcve] that outlines expected results

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in javascript will always have numeric indexes. To use indexing by "cars" instead of numbers, use object instead of array:

```
var myJsonArray = { baseID: '1', optionsArray: {} };

var myObj = {
"cars": [
    { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
    { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
    { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
]};

myJsonArray.optionsArray = Object.assign(myJsonArray.optionsArray, myObj);
```

result:

```
baseID: "1"
optionsArray: 
    cars: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    __proto__: Object__
proto__: Object
```